# Raster Calculator merge all DN values to '1'

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

The title of the question should say it all, but to elaborate...
I have a viewshed in raster format containing a mix of DN values and I
want to polygonise it. When I convert the raster output, the processing takes ages and the vector output generates loads of features.

The goal is to manipulate the raster to merge all DN values to '1' so that when I polygonise it, processing time is vastly reduced and the resulting feature count is also reduced.

It would also be good to know how to 'delete' values < '1' before polygonising (I have made DN values of 0 transparent in the screenshot).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge all values to 1 is a reclassify process. If this is into two categories, use Raster Calculator as:

```
"viewshed@1" > 0
```

I suppose that you want to keep all DN excluding negatives and 0. The output will be values 0's and 1's.

To delete 0's values, use again raster calculator:

```
"output@1" / "output@1"
```

The result will be values 1's and `no data`